# How much is too many ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, architecture, hosting

I want to develop a web application and I do not want to make my server crash. This is why I ask this question. How much ajax requests can a web server handle?

I know this will depend on the server and and the background actions (calling SQL Server, computation, ...) that need to be done before the aswser is provided to the ajax request.

Here is what I would need to do:

- For each client, 1 ajax request per second on an XML file
- I have a shared server at 1and1 (http://www.1and1.com/linux-web-hosting?linkId=hd.subnav.linuxhosting) the $4.99 one.

How many clients can I handle at the same time without any connection issues?

Comment: Only your server and your code can tell. You have to try it for yourself and see where it maxes out

Comment: You can ask to your host service what they recommend regarding your subscription but it answers only one part of the question, the other part is yours, what your app really need, how it is coded, and how many 'real users' you'll have at the same time...

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a load test to arrive at a number. You need to watch different parameters of your setup i.e. number of concurrent threads on Web/App Server. Number of database connections in the connection pool and so on.

You can use [**JMeter**](http://jmeter.apache.org) for performing a load test. You can send the data (which you are sending through AJAX) to URL using JMeter.